# Varchar(255) as MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM to Datetime format - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I know there are a million of these date conversion questions, but I can't find the specific one to solve my problem.

I have a table with a column `[Date]` that contains data that is formatted as `MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM`, but is stored as a `varchar`.

```
[Date] (varchar(255),null)
12/22/2017 0:34
12/21/2017 21:33
12/21/2017 21:17
...
```

I need to run a query and filter by date range, so I need to figure out how to convert to a usable datetime format.

I've tried

```
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), CAST([Date] AS DATETIME), 121) between @beg1 and @end1
```

But get the error

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

I've tried several other answers, but none were quite formatted the same as my data so the conversions didn't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: another good example why it's a really awful idea to store date values in a varchar column

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I completely agree

Comment: Then fix the design, @mikem115 , change the column to a Date and Time Datatype. `smalldatetime` might even be appropriate here.

Comment: On the topic of the question, a quick visit to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) will tell you why style code `121` (`yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss.mmm (24h)`) isn't working; and which will.

Comment: @Larnu I appreciate the input. unfortunately we're inheriting a very poorly managed DB through a company acquisition. I am a read-only analyst and our DBA's have much large fish to fry at the moment. Workarounds like these are going to be the norm for a couple weeks while they get through all the fixes. I checked the documentation and style code `22` is closest, but still doesn't work b/c of the year format.

Comment: You skipped the first couple of style: @mikem115 you want style 101 (`mm/dd/yyyy`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As many of us have mentioned, to *real* solution is fix the data type, which means altering the database.

First, to fix the data, you need to change the format to an ISO format, specifically here we're going to do with the ISO8601 format (`yyyy-mm-ddThh:mi:ss.mmm`). This will require a `TRY_CONVERT` and `CONVERT` (the first to change the data to a `smalldatetime` and the second to the formatted `varchar`):

```sql
UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET YourDate = CONVERT(varchar(20),TRY_CONVERT(smalldatetime, YourDate, 101), 126);
```

Now we can alter the data type (to a `smalldatetime` as your data is accurate to a minute:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ALTER COLUMN YourDate smalldatetime NULL;
```

*If* you "must" leave it at a `varchar` (this is a **bad** idea, as your data has so many problems is so), then you need to use `TRY_CONVERT` in the `WHERE`, with the correct style code:

```sql
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(smalldatetime, YourDate, 101)
```

This is, however, a really bad idea as your data is severely flawed. For example, according to your data, the "date" `'12/22/2017 0:34'` is **after** today (`'09/30/2020 21:25'`), not *before*.

Answer (score -4):

The code as you wrote it works fine. You probably have a badly formatted record or record where it is not in a date format. Try code like this to find those records. Any columns with a "NULL" value are ones where the try_cast could not succeed. These are the ones blowing up your query.

You can then choose to correct these values or simply exclude them from your query.

```
SELECT 
 [DateText], try_cast([DateText] AS Datetime) FROM Dates
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you've reposted your deleted answer, but this still won't work, for the reason I explain in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64144505/varchar255-as-mm-dd-yyyy-hhmm-to-datetime-format-mssql#comment113429400_64144505)

Comment: There's no such thing as a date format. Dates are binary values. Storing strings instead of bytes is a *major* bug

Comment: As indicated already, the submitter is inheriting a database. While you are correct that you should never store them as varchar, I have encountered this practice and had to clean it up. Try_Parse is one of those tools that is very helpful in doing so.

Comment: *"As indicated already, the submitter is inheriting a database."* And As they have inherited, they are now "in charge" of it, and so can fix the data.

Comment: And as I indicated, Try_Parse is a valuable tool in doing so. I am not arguing for storing dates as varchar, simply answering the submitter's question.

Comment: yes, we're inheriting a very poorly managed DB through a company acquisition. I am a read-only analyst and our DBA's have much large fish to fry at the moment. Workarounds like these are going to be the norm for a couple weeks while they get through all the fixes.

Comment: Give the above script a try and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: @mikem115 not knowing whether 4/7 is April 7 or July 4 is a pretty big fish - shark category

Comment: also, try_cast appears to have worked. There were `NULL` values in the column

Comment: @Larnu @Abraham Lincoln I ran it as `WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), TRY_CAST([Date] AS DATETIME), 22) between @beg2 and @end2` and it gave me output with no conversion errors. will parse though and verify the output is correct, but it's better than where I was

Comment: If you get null values, take a look at the format of the text that is actually there. Is it actually a date? Or did someone put completely invalid data in there.

Comment: ... have a look at my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64144505/varchar255-as-mm-dd-yyyy-hhmm-to-datetime-format-mssql#comment113429829_64144505),  @mikem115, `NULL` is no better than the correct value.

Comment: @Larnu the time component is not critical. I'm trying to pull survey results from 2020-07-01 through 2020-09-30. But that varchar [Date] column is all I have to filter on. If there is another way I should be writing that `WHERE` statement, let me know.

Comment: @AbrahamLincoln `101` preserves the time component.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as solved because I think the `try_cast` got me close enough for what we're trying to do. I know it may be a bit of a hack, and yes, we're definitely working on fixing the DB

Comment: *"the time component is not critical."* if the time part isn't important, then why not use a `date`... You have 6 [date and time types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/date-and-time-types?view=sql-server-ver15) to choose from, and none of them are `nvarchar`.

Comment: Just curious why you don't just use the TRY_CAST as it appears you are CASTing it to a datetime and then CONVERTing it back to a varchar(255).  And then doing a date range search where the optimizer will again have to convert it back to a datetime.

Comment: WHERE try_cast([DateText] AS Datetime) BETWEEN ... is likely sufficient.

Comment: @JMabee it was a hackjob from a different solution thread to this one that I hadn't completely eliminated. I ended up using the `try_cast` for this case as some others recommended. The ultimate solution is what @Larnu recommended with fixing the Table/Column itself.